# Use of !important! instead of !important in CSS?

Tags: html, css

We know how does `!important` hack works, as explained below.

CSS:

```css
p {
    color: red !important;
}
#para {
    color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<p id="para">Text will be in RED.</p>
```

The paragraph is will be displayed in red, even though the ID selector has higher specificity. The `!important` rule overrides that particular property.

My question is what does `!important!` (leading *and* trailing exclamation marks) does?

I've tried using `!important!` in my `CSS`, but I couldn't find any difference.

Comment: What makes you think it should do anything? Where did you pick that up?

Comment: I've seen it somewhere, but not sure of the source/reference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone just made a typo.

Comment: are you sure it wasn't a normal exclamation mark for grammar?

Comment: Or it wasn't something like ¡important!

Comment: What does ¡important! do?

Comment: The only variation that exists is `!important`, one exclamation mark in front. Everything else is gibberish and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Jon: Exclamation mark.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yea, just realized.

Comment: If `!important!` works the same as `!important`, it's probably just an accident due to poor coding in the browser. I'd be very surprised if it works cross-browser.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It's a typo, and it's not a real thing, and doesn't validate in W3 CSS validator. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator `Value Error : background Lexical error at line 2, column 31. Encountered: ";" (59), after : "!" !important;`

Comment: Maybe it means `very important` :D

Comment: Dunno maybe some CSS compiler like LESS had a variable or function named like this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a confusion caused by a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:

http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#unrecommended-important_exclam

It is an un-recommended hack.

From the above link:

Another problem with the !important identifier that wasn't fixed in IE 7 is the treatment of non-alphanumeric characters after the identifier. Normally, this should cause the property to fail, but Internet Explorer 7 and below ignore the additional punctuate and apply the property as if it just had the !important identifier.

The !important! identifier allows the property to be applied with importance in IE 7 and below and the property is not applied in other browsers. It may or may not work in future versions. Warning: this uses invalid CSS!

Comment: IE7. U gotta be kidding

Comment: Not only a hack, but also an obscure one. The official way to target IE <= 7 was (is?) the [star hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack).

Comment: I'll point out that this same page says that it was *fixed in IE7* ([under the main !important section](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css-important)), so this property would actually only affect IE6 and before.